TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError:
i am trying to send the transaction using node.js but i am getting this error every time.
TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 5FcAA4Yb8juHDfEQbYcxbwHrt5jRMnMf4LsCX4xY6SJaBPqMcipregCGcaZoyfozabq4YstUCFzmCJtvJ6iYJU29 has expired: block height exceeded.
at Connection.confirmTransactionUsingBlockHeightExceedanceStrategy (C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\jupiterSwap\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:6567:15)
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Connection.confirmTransaction (C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\jupiterSwap\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:6395:14)
at async Object.sendAndConfirmTransaction (C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\jupiterSwap\node_modules@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:2183:15)
at async sendSol (C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\jupiterSwap\server\cron\index.js:73:31)
at async swapAtRandom (C:\Users\abdul\Desktop\jupiterSwap\server\cron\index.js:106:23) {
signature: '5FcAA4Yb8juHDfEQbYcxbwHrt5jRMnMf4LsCX4xY6SJaBPqMcipregCGcaZoyfozabq4YstUCFzmCJtvJ6iYJU29'
}

Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?

I am also, tried a a lot.
      .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 300 }))
      .add(setComputeUnitPrice(umi, { microLamports: 10000000 }))
      .setFeePayer(userWalletSigner)
      .sendAndConfirm(umi, {
        send: {
          maxRetries: 1,
          skipPreflight: true,
          // preflightCommitment: "processed",
        },
        // confirm:{
        //   type: "finalized",
        // }
      });
    logger.info(`Minted ${metadata.name}`);


Here is my transaction using UMI and ive added the .add setCompute Limit and Price
P.S. Learning here.
